# How to configure mod_proxy_ajp to give different permissions to different apps in one virtual host?

Tags: tomcat, mod-proxy, apache-2.2, mod-proxy-ajp

On my server I have two tomcat applications: '*hidden*' and '*open*'. The *hidden* application should only be available for the local network *192.168.0.0*. The *open* app should be available for all networks.

The Applications run on Tomcat 7.0.6 and the requests are forewarded from Apache 2.2.17 with mod_proxy_ajp. All this runs on a FreeBSD 8.2 server.

The Apache web server also handles the root website, which is static. There is no virtual host configured (only one host).

I havn't found any example configuration so far, so I just tried to combine two simple configurations:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy /hidden>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168
</Proxy>

<Proxy /open>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /hidden ajp://localhost:8009/hidden/
ProxyPassReverse /hidden ajp://localhost:8009/hidden/

ProxyPass /open ajp://localhost:8009/open/
ProxyPassReverse /open ajp://localhost:8009/open/
```

With this configuration both applications are accessible from all networks. I already played with the Allow / Deny settings. This one seemed the most logical to me.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong with my configuration?

Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Proxy>` directive takes a full URL - since your virtualhost may have more than one of those, the directive is more suited to when you're using it as a full proxy.

Try changing your directives to `<Location>` blocks, that should apply the permissions in the way you want:

```
<Location /hidden>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168
</Proxy>

<Location /open>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```